# How to horizontal align social share buttons?

Tags: css, button, iframe, styles, social-networking

I have seen several sites where these `social share buttons` looks perfectly horizontal aligned. Take in account that many of these buttons are iframes.
Here is my current painful situation:
[image]

Comment: HTML and CSS will go a long way to helping you. Pretty much impossible to figure out from just a picture.

Comment: screenshots only help if there's code associated with it.

Comment: Of course that must be done with css (that's why I tag with `css` and `style`)! I ask for a general tip that take in account a similar situation. This is a question for `designers` more than just coders.

Comment: We can help you very easily in this situation but at least provide the code/fiddle so we can see where is the problem, because all the codes are in iframes and there css is also different but as per our need we have to adjust the css.

Comment: @IgorParra, I woud say the task is not for designers, but for coders, because aligning elements on a page is a css job and not photoshop, corel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `margin-top` on your iframes (or a `div` element above it) to negative values to have them line up. Use trial-and-error once you identify the correct elemtn until you get it right, for example using the following HTML:

```
<div id="twitter">
  <iframe/>
</div>
<div id="facebook">
  <iframe/>
</div>
<div id="digg">
  <iframe/>
</div>
```

The CSS would look something like this:

```
div#facebook 
{
  margin-top:-5px;
}
div#digg 
{
  margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did it in that way, Thanks,.-